# Installing Virtual Environment with PIP for Python Via Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip

So, just a quick question. I've installed Pip for Python via Homebrew in the Mac OS X terminal. The next thing I tried to do was install the virtual environment via pip install virtualenv --and that's where I ran into a problem. I get the following error message:

```
 Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py'
```

Anyone know what to do?
I'm new to all this, so I'm completely at a loss as to what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: You need root permissions to install a package globally.

Comment: To elevate your permissions, put `sudo` in front of your command i.e. `sudo pip install virtual env`

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://softwaretester.info/install-and-upgrade-pip-on-mac-os-x/
this might help you i am windows user so its command is like **pip install package-name** but you must present in **Scripts folder of the python27** in windows but i don't know about the mac-os-x . so do this also change your directory to **python27/scripts** and then use your command of pip

---

If this helps you.Support with thumbs up